# Transfer Bitcoins From Bitcoin Core To Blockchain Wallet?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, bitcoin-core

I used to have Bitcoin core on another computer and kept it on C drive with 2TB hard drive. I kept the dat on a USB.

However it broke and on my new computer the C drive is a fast but small drive that doesn't have the space to download the blocks now. So after a google search i found some info to use my D drive for the downloads which i have done.

The problem is every time i load the software it seems to need to verify the blocks as if there is some error and constantly stays on 3 years and 7 weeks behind and never seems to get further. My internet speed is ok but not ultra fast also so the software wallet just seems like a nightmare to use now as the balance remains at 0 and i can't seem to do any transfers until all the blocks have updated i guess. Why the wallet can't do a quick blockchain based balance update to save people from this serious problem i have no idea.

I have about $50 in bitcoin in the Bitcoin Core wallet though and would like to transfer it to the online Blockchain wallet, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. To transfer the bitcoins out without synchronising the blockchain, you'll have to create a signed raw transaction and broadcast it with a third-party provider (such as blockchain.info). You can lookup the input from a blockchain hosted on a third party provider.

`bitcoin-cli help createrawtransaction`

Comment: Thanks, is there a tutorial how to do this anywhere?